Hotel transfer from Varadero Airport without cash
A friend of mine is arriving at Varadero Airport and needs transportation to her hotel by taxi, shared minibus, or similar.  (She doesn't speak Spanish, has a lot of bags, and is not familiar with the area, so taking public transit is not a good option.)  The hotel does not provide a transfer service.  She does not have much cash and is arriving from a country where it will be difficult or impossible to get USD, CAD, EUR, etc.  She does have Canadian debit and credit cards.
Do any taxis leaving from Varadero Airport accept credit cards?  Or is there a desk or kiosk at the airport where she can order a taxi (or similar) and pre-pay with a credit card?  Or does the airport have an ATM where she can use her debit card to withdraw pesos to pay a taxi in cash?
If there's no possibility of using a card at the airport to pay for a taxi, can she book and pay for one online in advance?  Web searches turn up a few sites purporting to offer such transfers but I have no way of judging their safety and reliability.

If she has Canadian cards why doesn't she have dollars? Although $CA dollars aren't as useful as $US or €. If she wants to book online, just do a bit of research into the taxi company. They have a reputation to consider, and she has some protection from the card issuer. There's a ton of information when you google Varadero Airport taxis. Some airports have a kiosk at Arrivals where she can pay for a concession taxi, but such places are often overcrowded.

Cash is currently king in Cuba, despite the government’s efforts to force wider use of ‘cashless’ payment methods. I would be amazed if any taxis in Cuba accept card payment direct from the passenger at the start/end of the ride; even if they did it’s often hit and miss as to whether the payment system will actually be working.

@WeatherVane She's not travelling to Varedero from Canada and so can't get Canadian cash. I know that "some airports" have kiosks to book and pre-pay taxis; my question is specifically about whether Varadero is one such airport.

@Psychonaut: Can't she get USD or Euro at her departure airport? Even if these are hard to come by in country almost all international airports have some basic money exchange  facilities.

Related: https://hometohavana.com/blog/currency-in-cuba

I can now report back on how things went.
I tried to pre-book a taxi for my friend online.  The first step was to find a company offering this service.  Web searches turned up mostly (American) companies whose SEO strategy is to stuff their websites with keywords for various destinations, irrespective of whether they are actually capable of arranging taxi service there.  The only Cuba-based transfer company I found was All Cuba Travel, whose agent initially advised me to hire a taxi at the airport, despite my having explained to him that the passenger would have no USD, EUR, CAD, or CUP.  After I reminded him about this, he suggested instead that the passenger offer to pay the driver on arrival at the hotel, using the currency exchange office there to withdraw pesos.  Unfortunately, this also wouldn't work: upon checking with the hotel (whose telephone receptionist incidentally spoke no English) I discovered that their exchange office would be closed at that time.  The agent finally said that he would look into pre-booking a taxi that I would pay in advance with my credit card, but he never got back to me.
In the end, my friend was able, at considerable inconvenience, to scrape together enough foreign cash before departure to pay for a one-way taxi ride.  She did check Varadero Airport for an ATM or currency exchange office anyway, but didn't find one.  (Admittedly she didn't check too thoroughly as she was in a hurry.)
For the return trip to the airport, rather than using the hotel's currency exchange office to withdraw pesos, she consulted the hotel staff.  One employee had a husband who was a taxi driver and had a Canadian bank account to which my friend was able to transfer money.  (She was worried that this would turn out to be a scam, but given the low stakes she decided to trust the employee, and her husband indeed arrived as promised to drive her.)
TLDR version:

Don't put yourself in a situation where you arrive in Cuba without prearranged transport from the airport and without cash to hire such transport on the spot.
Don't assume you will be able to exchange or withdraw cash at the airport or even at your hotel; get confirmation first that an ATM or exchange office exists and will be in operation at the time you arrive.
Don't rely on any company that offers to book a prepaid taxi for you.


Upvoted as you came back and shared the details of your experience. This is invaluable to the community. I wouldn't characterize having sufficient foreign currency as a considerable inconvenience though, this is just one of those things that you have to do on any international trip.

@nikhil It was a considerable inconvenience to my friend, who was travelling from a country where foreign cash is generally unavailable, and whose local currency would not have been accepted by Cuban taxi drivers.

"using the hotel's currency exchange office" why would anyone do that, given that Cuba has ATMs?

@njzk2 Not every hotel/resort has an ATM.  The one my friend was staying at didn't, but it did have a currency exchange office.

@njzk2 Cuba has ATMs, but they are often out of service because a) they’re broken b) they’ve run out of cash c) communication connections are down due to a power cut. If you do find one that’s working, there’ll likely be a long queue to use it (resulting in b) above). Cuban taxi drivers will likely prefer US$  because that’s probably the currency they need to purchase gasoline

@Traveller is this a recent state of affairs? I don't remember it being the case a few years ago

@njzk2 Since the pandemic. Progressively worse as time goes on eg last week’s island-wide electricity grid failure. Tourism has never recovered after Covid, the economy has collapsed and the health system is in tatters, and a migration crisis has seen c2m Cubans leave.


Do any taxis leaving from Varadero Airport accept credit cards?

If it’s a private hire from the taxi rank outside (if there are any given the fuel shortage) almost certainly not. If there is a kiosk at the airport where you can book a state taxi (typically a yellow cab) on arrival, maybe, depending on whether the card payment system is working. (Not the same scenario, but as an example last time I was in Cuba a few months ago I waited an hour to pay for breakfast at a 5* hotel because the connection for their card terminals was down, and ended up paying in cash).

is there a desk or kiosk at the airport where she can order a taxi (or similar) and pre-pay with a credit card?

Maybe/probably not. Varadero Airport only mentions the taxi rank outside the terminal building, however the information may not be up-to-date given that it also refers to CUC, which hasn’t been an official currency since the Cuban Government eliminated it in 2021.

does the airport have an ATM where she can use her debit card to withdraw pesos to pay a taxi in cash?

Maybe, but if there is I wouldn’t rely on it being working or actually having any cash. The website linked above says there’s a Forex Bureau, however. It doesn’t say if the Bureau accepts cards.

if there's no possibility of using a card at the airport to pay for a taxi, can she book and pay for one online in advance?

I don’t see why not. Just do the usual research to check out the company before booking.
TLDR: Do the research and pre-book. I’ve visited Cuba 20+ times. Pre-Covid, arriving there without much cash and relying on there being taxis outside the airport, using ATMs/cards in shops, hotels etc, was usually fine. Now, however, I would not recommend it. It might be ok, but there are a myriad of reasons why it might not be, ranging from power cuts affecting services to lack of supplies of virtually anything, including cash in ATMs.

This answer would be much improved by explaining what is meant by "usual research to check out the company".  What criteria, specifically, should we be using to determine whether a pre-booked taxi company is legitimate and reliable?
